# Removing the breadcrumb from frontpage

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'd like to remove the breadcrumb from the frontpage and haven't been able to find a solution in the configuration settings of the theme or custom breadcrumbs. So I am thinking of modifying the page.tpl.php

Do you see a problem with this?

Replace:

```
<?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
```

With:

```
<?php if ($_GET["q"] == variable_get("site_frontpage",
"node")){}
else if ($breadcrumb) {print $breadcrumb;} ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do it the hard way. There is a variable (bool) $is_front that you can use in this case.

```
<?php if (!$is_front && $breadcrumb) {
  print $breadcrumb;
}
?>
```

You can read more about page.tpl.php variables [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7).

Comment: There is also a function [drupal_is_front_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7).